# How to provide Dockerfile for mlflow models build-docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mlflow

I have created a Model using pyfunc file with mlflow which usage a conda_env to install packages required for model.

```
pip_env = {
    'pip': [
        'pandas==0.24.1',
        'python-dateutil==2.8.1',
        'fuzzywuzzy==0.7.0'
    ]
}
conda_env = {
    'channels': ['defaults'],
    'dependencies': [
        'python=3.7.0',
        'pip=20.2.3',
        pip_env
    ]
}
mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path=model_path, python_model=gfeCleanPrediction(), artifacts=artifacts, conda_env=conda_env,code_path=code_path)
```

I need to use my own Dockerfile which will build some packages from source and install, Is there a way I can provide it while running below command :

```
mlflow  models build-docker -m MODEL_FOLDER_V-1-0-1 -n my_model --install-mlflow
```

I can see mlflow provide a custom_setup_steps_hook parameter in /python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/models/docker_utils.py

```
def _build_image(image_name, entrypoint, mlflow_home=None, custom_setup_steps_hook=None):
    """
    :param custom_setup_steps_hook: (Optional) Single-argument function that takes the string path
           of a dockerfile context directory and returns a string containing Dockerfile commands to
           run during the image build step.
    """
    mlflow_home = os.path.abspath(mlflow_home) if mlflow_home else None
    with TempDir() as tmp:
        cwd = tmp.path()
        install_mlflow = _get_mlflow_install_step(cwd, mlflow_home)
        custom_setup_steps = custom_setup_steps_hook(cwd) if custom_setup_steps_hook else ""
        with open(os.path.join(cwd, "Dockerfile"), "w") as f:
            f.write(
                _DOCKERFILE_TEMPLATE.format(
                    install_mlflow=install_mlflow,
                    custom_setup_steps=custom_setup_steps,
                    entrypoint=entrypoint,
                )
            )
```

How to use custom_setup_steps_hook OR use my own Dockerfile in **mlflow  models build-docker**??

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is build an image the way mlflow wants you to (lets call it `base-mlflow-image`) and then use that as the base image in your custom dockerfile so start it with:

```
FROM base-mlflow-image

... install your custom packages
```

then use that image to deploy your model

Comment: do you have an example image?